# Dividing by Random.next always results in 0?

Tags: c#, random, division

This one is really puzzling me. I am writing a damage algorithm with some random variation. When I calculate the variation this is what it looks like.

```
Random random = new Random();
Double variation = random.Next(85, 115) / 100;
Double damage = restOfAlgorithm * variation;
```

When I do that, variation always outputs 0. However, if I do like below, it will output the expected result.

```
Random random = new Random();
Double variation = random.Next(85, 115);
Double damage = restOfAlgorithm * (variation / 100);
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: First of all it is `Next`, not `next`. Try `random.Next(85, 115) / 100.0;` to avoid **integer division**

Comment: Because you're doing integer division?

Comment: 100 is an int. `(double)100`

Comment: @I4V It have it like that in my code, edited the question.

Comment: Use `random.Next(85, 115) / 100d;`

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, Jonsey I'll try that.

Comment: Or use 100d to avoid integer division

Comment: @Jonesy It works now. I feel like a total idiot. Please leave it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide by a double:

```
Double variation = random.Next(85, 115) / 100.0;
```

or

```
Double variation = random.Next(85, 115) / (double)100;
```

Otherwise you'll be doing integer arithmetic (since `Random.Next` returns an integer and 100 is also integer).

I consider it best practice to know what types you are working with and cast everything to the type desired.  Certainly this is more than is necessary, as the compiler will implicitly convert values.  But with explicit casts your intentions are then visible to someone looking at the code later.

```
Double variation = (double)random.Next(85, 115) / 100d;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `random.Next` will give you an integer and 100 is also an integer. So dividing them will either result in 0 or 1 depending if your random number if below or above 100. You need to divide by `100.0` in order to get a double division.

Answer (score 1):

The method `random.Next(lower_bound, upper_bound)` returns an integer value (`int` type). In the first case you have `random.Next(85, 115) / 100` and this is a division of int variables. In C# it implies integer division (when both numbers and ints). That is why it sometimes returns 0.
In the second case you use `variation` which is of type double. That is why C# converts the result to double and then everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else Mentioned: `random.Next()` will return an integer.

Instead use: `random.NextDouble()`, this will give you a nice double to calculate with, as it returns a double between 0 and 1 that you can process further to fit your range.

```
double variation = random.NextDouble() * range + minimum;
```

alternatively you can divide by double as mentioned in the other answers:

```
double variation = random.Next(minimum, minimum + range) / 1.0 /*or*/ (double)1
```