# C# error in dividing two integers

Tags: c#

i have this following code to calculate the percentace in perst, but when i run this code I always get o as value in perst for all values of qxount and acount.

```
int perst;
int qcount;
int acount;

perst = (acount / qcount) * 100;
```

Comment: you cannot divide by zero.

Comment: Multiply acount by 100 before dividing it, it's just an integer rouding issue

Comment: To expand, those variables have not be initialized, and have a default value of 0.

Comment: Your code, as is, won't compile.  Please provide example code that compiles, runs, exhibits behavior that you've explained (does it error, produce incorrect output, what?) and also explain what you *want* it to do.

Comment: Try initializing the values. And you probably want to do `((double)acount / qcount) * 100;` to get fractions.

Comment: Initialize your variables, and know that all decimals will be truncated if you divide integers together.

Comment: @AlexH it'll still be zero.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar It still *won't compile*.

Comment: @Servy, pff. A mere technicality. (Kidding, you win...this time).

Comment: always [know what types you are working with, know how integer and mixed-mode arithmetic works, and cast](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18991191/571637)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dividing integers the result will be an integer. This means that you are expecting a value such as 0.75 (which you appear to be thinking you'll multiply by 100 to get a percentage) then the integer value returned will be only the 0 which is the leading integer. The remainder would be available with the % modulus operator.

However, get a percentage like you seem to want, you'll need to divide using doubles or float values.

```
double perst;
double qcount;
double acount;

perst = (acount / qcount) * 100;
```

The MSDN article on the division operator - [Good idea to read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx).

Comment: He has several problems with the post/code that need to be addressed before he even gets to this point.

Comment: @Servy: Agreed, but my assumption is that he has simply left out a few implementation details that can be extrapolated. Reading his question, my thinking leads me to believe that OP has a fundamental misunderstanding of how dividing integers works. My answer is written with this in mind. Perhaps I should put a link to a good document with this training in it.

Comment: Regardless, it's better to help the OP fix the question into one of sufficient quality that you don't *need* to be guessing what the problem is, especially when there are several likely candidates.

Comment: @Servy: Again, agreed. As you can read from the comments, there are plenty of people (yourself included) already covering that topic. If you have something constructive to say, please say it, otherwise, be a dear - downvote and move on.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you should vote to close and *not answer an unclear question* rather than guessing and trying to answer a question with insufficient detail to provide an answer.  Answering unclear questions results in low quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some integer rounding issues. Try something like this.

```
int perst;
int qcount = 100;
int acount = 5;

perst = Convert.ToInt32(((double)acount / (double)qcount) * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

While rounding is almost certainly the mistake (after assigning values to the variables) the following works just fine:

```
int a = 62;
int b = 235;
int percentage = 100*a/b;
Console.WriteLine(percentage);
```

You don't need to use doubles. This rounds the percentage towards zero. If you need more precise results, go with double or single.

Comment: More accurately, this process "floors" the percentage. `26.9%` would still be only `26%`.